# Позиционирование ячейки таблицы

Tags: html, css

Добавляю через js в конец еще один `td` с `position: absolute`. Сам `tr` имеет `position: relative`, но этот последний `td` позиционируется от общего окна, а не от `tr`.

Как все же сделать так, что бы эта ячейка позиционировалась от своего родительского `tr`?

```
<tr class="dif_color">
    <td class="link_a"></td>
    <td class="link_a"></td>
    <td class="link_a"></td>
    <td class="link_a">
        <button type="button" class="btn_accept" data-id="1098">ACCEPT</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn_decline" data-id="1098">DECLINE</button>
    </td>    
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Все на месте:

```css
tr {
  position: relative;
}

.add {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
       <tr class="dif_color">
            <td class="link_a">Lorem</td>
            <td class="link_a">Lorem</td>
            <td class="link_a">Lorem</td>
            <td class="link_a">
              <button type="button" class="btn_accept" data-id="1098">ACCEPT</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn_decline" data-id="1098">DECLINE</button>
            </td>  
         
         <td class="add">add</td>
  </tr>
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае нужно добавить для `tr` свойство `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

Согласно [уже данным ответам](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564638/using-position-relative-absolute-within-a-td):

> This is because according to CSS 2.1, the effect of position: relative
>   on table elements is undefined.
>   Что по сути означает, что мы не можем к нашему display: table добавлять этот параметр.